# One table view cell/row bigger than others?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I know it is possible to set the height of all rows in a UITable but is it possible to set one row to be bigger than the others.
For example when the user touches on the cell with 2 fingers I want the cell to expand and show a description. But only that cell. Is that possible without overlapping the cells below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the UITableViewDelegate method [`heightForRowAtIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW25)

Say that your data model stored objects that have a `height` property:

```
 - ( void ) changeHeightForRowAtIndexPath: ( NSIndexPath *) indexPath ( NSInteger ) height {
    [ myData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row ].height = height;
    [ myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [ NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath ] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone ];
 }
```

Comment: But I won't be able to change the height of the row when I like? Only when the TableViewController "asks" for it

Comment: Just call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` with a one-element `NSArray`.

Comment: You want to persist cell height?

Comment: Jonathan: Just return the correct height in `-heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 1):

Override this method `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: He is asking for an animation that dynamically changes the height.  heightForRowAtIndexPath is run prior to the table setup and won't change the height with user interaction.